# Text from threejs won't load at all, causing a black screen, despite being formatted the exact same as the rest of the objects

Tags: java, html, css, three.js

I am trying to load text as an object in threejs, and it is formatted the exact same way as every other object, but for some reason it causes a black screen.

I've tried to reformat it in multiple forms and nothing seems to work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
      renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
      renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

      var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
      light.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );      //default; light shining from top           // default false
      scene.add( light );

      var geometryBall = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0);
      var geometryPlayerA = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.20, 1.35, 3);
      var geometryPlayerB = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.20, 1.35, 3);
      var geometryGoal = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.5, 15, 27.75);
      var geometryWall = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(40, 15, 0.5);
      var geometryCeiling = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(21, 0.20, 15);
      var geometryFloor = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(21, 0.20, 15);

      var loaderA = new THREE.FontLoader();
      loaderA.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
                var geometryTextA = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry( 'Scoreboard', {
                    font: font,
                    size: 80,
                    height: 5,
                    curveSegments: 12,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 10,
                    bevelSize: 8,
                    bevelOffset: 0,
                    bevelSegments: 5
                });
      });

      var loaderB = new THREE.FontLoader();
      loaderB.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
                var geometryTextB = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry( 'Scoreboard', {
                    font: font,
                    size: 80,
                    height: 5,
                    curveSegments: 12,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 10,
                    bevelSize: 8,
                    bevelOffset: 0,
                    bevelSegments: 5
                });
      });

      var materialPlayerA = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff } );
      var materialPlayerB = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8000 } );
      var materialBall = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
      var materialGoal = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
      var materialWall = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0 } );
      var materialCeiling = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0 } );
      var materialFloor = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0 } );
      var materialTextA = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff } );
      var materialTextB = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8000 } );

      var wireframePlayerA = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryPlayerA );
      var wireframePlayerB = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryPlayerB );
      var wireframeBall = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryBall );
      var wireframeGoal = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryGoal );
      var wireframeWall = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryWall );
      var wireframeCeiling = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryCeiling );
      var wireframeFloor = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryFloor );
      var wireframeTextA = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryTextA );  
      var wireframeTextB = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( geometryTextB );        

      var wallA = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeWall, materialWall );
      var wallB = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeWall, materialWall );
      var playerA = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframePlayerA, materialPlayerA );
      var playerB = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframePlayerB, materialPlayerB );
      var ball = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeBall, materialBall );
      var goalA = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeGoal, materialGoal );
      var goalB = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeGoal, materialGoal );
      var ceiling = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeCeiling, materialCeiling );
      var floor = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeFloor, materialFloor );
      var textA = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeTextA, materialTextA );
      var textB = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeTextB, materialTextB );

      var wireframeoutlineTextA = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0x00ffff, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshtextA = new THREE.Mesh( geometryTextA, materialTextA );
      scene.add( meshtextA );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshtextA.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshtextA.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineTextB = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xff8000, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshtextB = new THREE.Mesh( geometryTextB, materialTextB );
      scene.add( meshtextB );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshtextB.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8000, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshtextB.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineBall = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0x00ff00, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshball = new THREE.Mesh( geometryBall, materialBall );
      scene.add( meshball );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshball.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xf00ff00, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshball.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlinePlayerA = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0x00ffff, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshplayerA = new THREE.Mesh( geometryPlayerA, materialPlayerA );
      scene.add( meshplayerA );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshplayerA.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshplayerA.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlinePlayerB = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xff8000, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshplayerB = new THREE.Mesh( geometryPlayerB, materialPlayerB );
      scene.add( meshplayerB );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshplayerB.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8000, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshplayerB.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineGoalA = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xff0000, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshGoalA = new THREE.Mesh( geometryGoal, materialGoal );
      scene.add( meshGoalA );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshGoalA.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshGoalA.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineGoalB = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xff0000, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshGoalB = new THREE.Mesh( geometryGoal, materialGoal );
      scene.add( meshGoalB );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshGoalB.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshGoalB.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineWallA = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xC0C0C0, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshWallA = new THREE.Mesh( geometryWall, materialWall );
      scene.add( meshWallA );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshWallA.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshWallA.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineWallB = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xC0C0C0, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshWallB = new THREE.Mesh( geometryWall, materialWall );
      scene.add( meshWallB );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshWallB.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshWallB.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineFloor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xC0C0C0, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshFloor = new THREE.Mesh( geometryFloor, materialFloor );
      scene.add( meshFloor );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshFloor.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshFloor.add( wireframe );

      var wireframeoutlineCeiling = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
          color : 0xC0C0C0, 
          polygonOffset : true, 
          polygonOffsetFactor : 1,
          polygonOffsetUnits : 1  
      } );
      var meshCeiling = new THREE.Mesh( geometryCeiling, materialCeiling );
      scene.add( meshCeiling );
      var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshCeiling.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
      var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC0C0C0, linewidth: 2 } );
      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
      meshCeiling.add( wireframe );

      meshGoalA.position.set(-20, 0, 0);
      goalA.position.set(-20, 0, 0);
      goalA.material.depthTest = true;
      goalA.material.opacity = 0.15;
      goalA.material.transparent = true;

      meshGoalB.position.set(20, 0, 0);
      goalB.position.set(20, 0, 0);
      goalB.material.depthTest = true;
      goalB.material.opacity = 0.15;
      goalB.material.transparent = true;

      meshplayerB.position.set(-6, 0, 0);
      playerB.position.set(-6, 0, 0);
      playerB.material.depthTest = true;
      playerB.material.opacity = 0.15;
      playerB.material.transparent = true;

      meshplayerA.position.set(6, 0, 0);
      playerA.position.set(6, 0, 0);
      playerA.material.depthTest = true;
      playerA.material.opacity = 0.15;
      playerA.material.transparent = true;

      meshWallA.position.set(0, 0, 14);
      wallA.position.set(0, 0, 14);
      wallA.material.depthTest = true;
      wallA.material.opacity = 0.15;
      wallA.material.transparent = true;

      meshWallB.position.set(0, 0, -14);
      wallB.position.set(0, 0, -14);
      wallB.material.depthTest = true;
      wallB.material.opacity = 0.15;
      wallB.material.transparent = true;

      meshball.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      ball.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      ball.material.transparent = true;
      ball.material.depthTest = true;
      ball.material.opacity = 0.15;

      meshFloor.position.set(0, -4, 0);
      floor.position.set(0, -4, 0);
      floor.material.depthTest = true;
      floor.material.opacity = 0.15;
      floor.material.transparent = true;

      meshCeiling.position.set(0, 4, 0);
      ceiling.position.set(0, 4, 0);
      ceiling.material.depthTest = true;
      ceiling.material.opacity = 0.15;
      ceiling.material.transparent = true;

      meshtextA.position.set(5, 5, 14);
      textA.position.set(5, 5, 14);
      textA.material.depthTest = true;
      textA.material.opacity = 0.15;
      textA.material.transparent = true;

      meshtextB.position.set(-5, 5, 14);
      textB.positon.set(-5, 5, 14);
      textB.material.depthTest = true;
      textB.material.opacity = 0.15;
      textB.material.transparent = true;

      var paddles = new THREE.Group(); 
      paddles.add( playerA );
      paddles.add( playerB );

      var borders = new THREE.Group();
      borders.add( wallA );
      borders.add( wallB );
      borders.add( ceiling );
      borders.add( floor );

      var goals = new THREE.Group();
      goals.add( goalA );
      goals.add( goalB );

      var scoreboard = new THREE.Group();
      scoreboard.add( textA );
      scoreboard.add( textB );

      scene.add( paddles );
      scene.add( borders );
      scene.add( goals );
      scene.add( scoreboard );

      scene.add( ball );

      camera.position.z = 5;

      function animate() {


        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }
      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A black screen is all that I see after loading it, despite it being formatted the exact same way.

Comment: this question should be tagged with threejs. Aframe is referenced but never used. Here is a good tutorial on how to use html text in threeJS. https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-align-html-elements-to-3d.html

Comment: @ThomasWilliams I don't have the reputation to tag with ThreeJS.  Also, I did use the tutorial and still could not figure out what I was supposed to do specifically, hence why I am now here to ask for help.  I appreciate what you did, however.

Comment: you should be able to use the threejs tag regardless of your reputation. maybe try removing the other tags (java, css, html). If you are getting a black screen, it is probably an error. Open the console (rt click on the screen > Inspect, then console tab) and look for errors. That tutorial provides working code, so you should be able to compare it to yours, or import the working code. I am not a threejs expert, so I am not quite qualified to debug your code. If you want to go the Aframe route, check out this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHWO-nWWe5w

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Still can't use the tag, it takes 1500 reputation.  Also, I figured out the issue, but it's not something I'll be able to bypass, due to it being some policy issue, I'll copy it beflow.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at [my file area] from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I tried to copy just the file itself and put it into the right folder directory, but it still gave me the same error, just without the null.

Comment: I fixed the tags